# How do I do user inputs

Tags: python-3.x

What I wish to do is ask a question to the user (user inputs) (Answers: Yes, No) if they say yes, something happens, if they say no, something else happens.

I.E:
I ask the user if they want to have a race in how fast they can type compared to the computer. If they say yes, we have a race, if they say no, i can continue with something else.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is [input](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input):

```
user_input = input('Yes or No?: ')
if user_input == 'Yes':
    print('You said yes!')
elif user_input == 'No':
    print('You said no!')
else:
    print('You said neither.')
```

If you want to ensure that the user that the user inputs either Yes or No then you can do:

```
while True:
    user_input = input('Yes or No?: ')
    if user_input in ['Yes', 'No']:
        break
    else:
        print('That is not a valid option!')

if user_input == 'Yes':
    print('You said yes!')
else:
    print('You said no!')
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Anybody using Python 2.x should use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: And how do I make it so if you do pick yes, it starts something, but if you pick no, it starts something else. For example if you say "Yes" you have a typing contest, if you say "No" you will skip this and go to the next thing.

Comment: @user2712431 Please **read** and **use your brain.** The answer *just showed you how to do it.*